# Percent operator in makefile isn't working for subfolder

Tags: makefile

In my `Makefile`, I have the following target:

```
%: %.sv
  $(VCC) $(VFLAGS) $^
```

Any file in the current directory with the extension `.sv` (system verilog) is captured in this. This works perfectly if I run the following command:

```sh
make alu
```

I have targets set up for building simulation `C++` files which are dependent on the specific system verilog targets above:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_alu: sim_alu.cc alu | $(BUILD_DIR)
   $(CC) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -Wall -Wno-sign-compare
```

These work fine when I run the following command:

```sh
make build/sim_alu
```

But expanding on this, in the same `Makefile`, if I replace the target above with this one, it fails with the error "No rule to make target":

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_%: sim_%.cc % | $(BUILD_DIR)
   $(CC) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -Wall -Wno-sign-compare
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: FYI, `BUILD_DIR` is created as follows:

```
$(BUILD_DIR):                                                                                                                          
   mkdir -p $@
```

Comment: Your `%: ...` rule is a _non-terminal match-anything pattern roule_. From [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules): "_A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a prerequisite of an implicit rule_". This is why your second pattern rule is not a candidate to build `$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_alu`. Match-anything pattern rules must be used with care because they are handled differently from other pattern rules. In your answer you used a _static pattern rule_ instead of a match-anything pattern rule, and this solves the issue.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - But I didn't change anything in the target `$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_%` did I? How is it a static pattern rule in my answer but a non-terminal match-anything pattern in my question? It's still a mystery to me.

Comment: It is the `%: %.sv` non-terminal match-anything pattern rule that you changed for the `$(MODULES): % : %.sv` static pattern rule. Not the other one. And thanks to this, it is not a non-terminal match-anything pattern rule any more. It matches only for the listed targets in `$(MODULES)`, not for anything that has no other candidate rule.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - I see, thanks for explaining. If you don't mind copy pasting your two comments into an answer, I'll be happy to accept your answer as it does explain how to fix my issue.

Comment: Done. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your:

```
%: %.sv
    $(VCC) $(VFLAGS) $^
```

rule is a non-terminal [match-anything pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules). From GNU make documentation:

> A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a prerequisite of an implicit rule.

This is why your second pattern rule is not a candidate to build `$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_alu`: one of its prerequisites (`alu`) is a target of your match-anything pattern rule. But the match-anything pattern rule does not apply, and you have no other rule, implicit or not, to build `alu`. So make does not know how to build `alu`, and thus also not how to build `$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_alu`.

Match-anything pattern rules must be used with care because they are handled differently from other pattern rules. In your answer you used the static pattern rule:

```
$(MODULES): % : %.sv
    $(VCC) $(VFLAGS) $^
```

instead of a match-anything pattern rule, and this solves the issue. The static pattern rule matches only for the listed targets in $(MODULES).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know why, but it suddenly started working.

In case it helps anyone else, here is my entire `Makefile`:

```
CC=g++    
VCC=verilator    
VFLAGS=-Wall -cc -build --trace    
STD=-std=c++17    
CFLAGS=-I$(VERILATOR_ROOT)/include -Iobj_dir obj_dir/*.o $(VERILATOR_ROOT)/include/verilated.cpp $(VERILATOR_ROOT)/include/verilated_vcd_c.cpp        
BUILD_DIR=build    
MODULES=alu comp zero_ext pcmodule pcadder extend register_file inst_rom    
SIMS=sim_alu sim_zero_ext sim_extend sim_register_file sim_inst_rom                
                                                                                   
.PHONE: all clean $(BUILD_DIR)                                                     
                                                                                   
all: $(MODULES) $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(SIMS))                                 
                                                                                  
$(BUILD_DIR)/sim_%: sim_%.cc % | $(BUILD_DIR)                                     
  $(CC) $(STD) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< -Wall -Wno-sign-compare                         
                                                                                  
$(MODULES): % : %.sv                                                  
  $(VCC) $(VFLAGS) $^                                                   
                                                                        
$(BUILD_DIR):                                                           
  mkdir -p $@                                                           
                                                                        
clean:                                                                  
  rm -rf build; rm -rf obj_dir
```